# Writing postgresql method on model to get datetime entries by day of week

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I have a column in one of my model's (team_opps) that is a datetime column called start_date.  I recently migrated my db from sqlite3 to postgresql and this blew up the method.

Here is the method that was working in sqlite3:

```
  def self.monday_team_opps
    where('strftime("%w", "start_date") = "?"', 1)
  end
```

The error that it gives is:

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "%w" does not exist
```

Meaning it doesn't like the strftime.  Can anyone clarify what needs to be adjusted to make this work in pgsql?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried escaping it? Using the format `.where('query ?', strftime("%w", start_date))` it might work.

Comment: since your start_date is a datetime and you are making queries based on date (at the db level), you might have a subtle timezone error - i blogged on this here - http://jessehouse.com/blog/2013/11/15/working-with-timezones-and-ruby-on-rails/ might be of interest

Comment: `strftime` is an SQLite-ism. And standard SQL uses single quotes for strings, double quotes are for identifiers such as table and column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
 def self.monday_team_opps
    where('EXTRACT(DOW FROM start_date) = ?', 1)
 end
```

Comment: this worked.  i'm assuming extract and dow is pgsql specific syntax.  never have seen this before.  thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
def self.monday_team_opps
  where("extract(day from start_date) = ?", 1)
end
```